# Installing SQL Server 2014 on Windows 2012 R2 Server is failing for remote and silent installation

Tags: sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2, silent-installer, sql-agent

We are trying to install SQL Server 2014 (unattended installation) on Windows Server 2012 R2 remotely using local user (added in Administrator group).

Failure and success Scenarios:

1. The installation (remote and silent) fails with the local user whereas it succeeds for Administrator user.
2. The installation succeeds if it is installed manually by logging in to server with local user.

Issues and errors:

using local user (added in administrator group):

1. SQL Server gets installed on Windows but some errors are reported in the summary log file like 'Unable to start Databases Handler'.
2. SQL Server Agent service fails to started manually or automatically.
   Tried to start the service with different service accounts but unable to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by **Enabling** The policy setting **"Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff "**

Steps:-

1. As an Administrator user, start the Windows Powershell (an icon can usually be found in the taskbar).
2. In the command prompt, type gpedit.msc. A Local Group Policy Editor window displays.
3. In the left pane, open Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > User Profiles
4. In the right pane, double-click on **"Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff."**
5. In the resulting window, click in the radio button **Enabled**.
6. Click OK.